# Declare an external local variable with a keyword?

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, external, keyword

I would like to understand why can't C++ provides a keyword to declare a variable in a called function, local to the calling function.
Actually, i need to inherit a vector class and i have to define the usual operations :

```
template <unsigned int N>
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector(const std::array<float, N>& coords);

    Vector<N>& operator*=(float k);
    // others...
protected:
    std::array<float, N> m_coords;
};

class Vector3 : public Vector<3>
{
public:
    Vector3(float x = 0.f, float y = 0.f, float z = 0.f);

    // some specific operations like cross product
}

template <unsigned int N>
Vector<N> operator*(float k, const Vector<N>& a)
{
    Vector<N> res(a);
    res *= k;
    return res;
}
```

Such a function would works for every inherited vector if i return a reference to a new object

```
template <unsigned int N>
Vector<N>& operator*(float k, const Vector<N>& a)
{
    Vector<N>* res = a.getClone();// virtual method returning a new object
    *res *= k;
    return &res;
}
```

However, i don't want to delete res in the calling function, so i want to create a variable local to the calling function.

Possible ?

Comment: @MohitJain That's what it is internally.

Comment: I don't really get the problem. ``Vector<N> operator* (float k, const Vector<N> & a) { return k * a; }`` should do the job, nah?

Comment: I am asking why you return a reference instead of a value, first and foremost. Your code as it is makes little sense. You claim to return a reference but you actually return a pointer (``return &res;``). The line ``*res *= k;`` implies, that Vector<N> type already has an operator *(float).

Comment: Vector3 = 5 * Vector<3>({1, 2, 3});

Comment: The code you show us should not even compile for the reasons I gave above.

Comment: sorry, please don't read the comment before. I wanted to say :
Vector3 = 5 * Vector3(1, 2, 3);
It don't works because the return type of opertor* is a Vector<3> and there is no copy constructor.

Comment: Never saw an ``operator *=`` to be honest. *giggles*. Change that member ``operator *=`` to a ``operator*`` which returns a value not a reference and you can simply write: ``return a * k;``. As your Vector is basically a "numeric type", you should give it the rule of 3 treatment: Copy constructor, operator=() and a destructor (while the latter is not really required).

Comment: 'External local' is a contradiction in terms. Your question does not make sense.

Comment: i am sorry, i would say "local to the calling function"

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i forgot the template approach for the external functions :

```
template <class T>
T operator*(float k, const T& a)
{
    T res(a);
    res *= k;
    return res;
}
```

Thus i can manipulate my hiding Vector<3> methods with Vector3.

I don't answered the keyword question however.